# Pandas - Extracting value from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in the below format. I am trying to break this into different rows for each key value pair.

```
id, data
101, [{'field': 'type1', 'newValue': '2020-01-16T12:35:50Z', 'oldValue': None}, 
      {'field': 'status', 'newValue': 'Started', 'oldValue': None}]
```

Expected output:

```
id, field, newValue, oldValue
101, type1, 2020-01-16T12:35:50Z, None
101, status, Started, None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [4432]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[101], 'data':[[{'field': 'type1', 'newValue': '2020-01-16T12:35:50Z', 'oldValue': None}, {'field': 'status', 'newValue': 'Started', 'oldValue': None}]]})

In [4438]: df1 = df.explode('data')['data'].apply(pd.Series)

In [4440]: df = pd.concat([df.id, df1], axis=1)

In [4441]: df
Out[4441]: 
    id   field              newValue oldValue
0  101   type1  2020-01-16T12:35:50Z     None
0  101  status               Started     None
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's `explode` the dataframe on `data` then create a new dataframe from exploded `data` column and finally use `join` :

```
out = df.explode('data').reset_index(drop=True)
out = out.join(pd.DataFrame(out.pop('data').tolist()))
```

---

```
print(out)

    id   field              newValue oldValue
0  101   type1  2020-01-16T12:35:50Z     None
1  101  status               Started     None
```